# Having Trouble Calling WordPress Plugin Form Value

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, plugins

My Plugin form code:

```
function pp_settings_page() {
    $pp_options = get_option('pp_options');
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Post Products Settings</h2>
        <form action="options.php" method="post">
            <?php settings_fields('pp_options_group'); ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">Currency sign: </th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="pp_options[currency_sign]" value="<?php echo $pp_options['currency_sign']; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Save changes" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

I have tried to call it within the template files using:

```
<?php $pp_options=get_option('pp_options');?>
```

and

```
<?php get_option('pp_options');?>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code to handle the form submit, more specifically, code which extracts the post variable and saves it using [update_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option)

Answer (score 0):

Your action would need to be changed to the settings page URL so when it gets posted it runs the next bit of code, which you would put inside your pp_settings_page function.

```
if(isset($_POST['field_name'])) {
    $field_value = $_POST['field_name'];
    update_option('option_name', $field_value);
}
```